# How can I use Cypress.io to assert that a file download has been initiated without actually downloading?

Tags: cypress

The download is initiated by setting

```
location.href = [some url to an image]
```

I want assert, as close as possible, that the download will succeed but without actually performing the download. That the URL is correct can be assumed.

Answer (score 2):

What you essentially want to do is stub a call to `location.href` using [`cy.stub()`](https://on.cypress.io/stub.html), **but** testing that your application has called `location.href` and asserting the `url` passed to it is a bit tricky since `href` is an attribute, not a function. Stubs cannot replace attributes, only functions.

This is testable with some restructure of your application code. There is a great answer on how to do this in this stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36678937/5878476